# getting access to nested data, eg to create a multiline graph in d3.v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

learning d3 here, and am finding things a little bit tough dealing with nested data. What I was wondering is whether, say I want to create a chart which is a set of time series off data nested using this code:

```
    d3.csv("DataTable.csv", function (data) {      

        var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%d/%m/%Y");

        var nested_data = d3.nest()
                .key(function(d) { return d.MasterKey; })    
                .key(function (e) { return d3.timeParse(e.StartDate);})        
                .rollup(function(g) { 
                return d3.sum(g, function(v) {return v.DatatoPlot; }); 
                })
                .entries(data)
```

Would it be better to restructure the data in some way, or eg use 'map' to replace the rollup? Basically I want to have a set of lines,  one for each element in MasterKey, which plots DatatoPlot vs StartDate. I find a lot of tutorials online don't really spend too much time on the nitty gritty with nested data structures,  which is why am finding it a little hard going finding my feet. Any advice on the above problem would be much appreciated, willing to do the hard work figuring out but a helpful nudge would be fantastic. Thanks.

Comment: please provide data so we can reproduce the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. To understand `d3.next()` I would avise to use `console.log(nested_data)` to see what does this fonction.

Comment: thanks yes I always use that diagnostic - the nesting structure is accurate based on that, although obviously I'm having an issue manipulating it. I'll append some reduced sample data to the post shortly, thanks again.

Comment: Again It is dificult to help you with no data example, and no code showing your attempt